# Do SELECT query based on statement returned from other SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
notifications
- email_address
- notification_email

users
- username
- domain
- notifications
```

My question is if I can build MySQL query which can do SELECT query based on statement returned from other SELECT without using scripting (Perl, Python, etc) and IF...ELSE statement?

Current code logic is set for queries below

```
SELECT notifications FROM users WHERE (username LIKE 'tester') AND (domain LIKE 'my.testdomain.com')

If notifications='Y' then

SELECT notification_email FROM notifications WHERE email_address = 'tester@my.testdomain.com'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the first query in a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT notification_email FROM notifications 
WHERE email_address = 'tester@my.testdomain.com'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM users 
    WHERE username LIKE 'tester' 
    AND domain LIKE 'my.testdomain.com'
    AND notifications = 'Y'
)
```

FYI, if you don't have any wildcard characters, `LIKE` is the same as `=`.

Comment: I have never thought to put that in a `WHERE` clause just to check if result `EXISTS`

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should have a foreign key link between notifications and users table.

Then your query would look like this:

```
SELECT
    notifications.notification_email
FROM
    notifications
        JOIN
    users ON (users.id = notifications.user_id)
WHERE
    users.username = 'tester'
        AND
    users.domain = 'my.testdomain.com'
        AND
    users.notifications = 'Y'
        AND
    notifications.email_address = 'tester@my.testdomain.com'
```

If there is no foreign key, there must be another way how the two tables are linked together (e.g. email). In such case you need to update the `ON` clause to connect the two tables together using columns containing equal data.

You might then not even need the `notifications.email_address = 'tester@my.testdomain.com'` condition.

Comment: Ideally I will do that way (using `JOIN`) but there is nothing to do that on.

Comment: @JackTheKnife Perhaps you could join on `email_address = CONCAT(username, '@', domain)`?